# tabulator - how to display a loading indicator while data is fetched from db based on a prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabulator

I created a tabulator component in my vue app and I am passing Tabulator options `data` and `columns` via props as following:

```js
// parent component
<template>
    <div>
        <Tabulator :table-data="materialsData" :table-columns="options.columns" :is-loading="materials.isLoading" />
    </div>
</template>

...
```

```js
// Tabulator component
props: {
    tableData: {
        type: Array,
        default: function() {
            return [
                { name: "Billy Bob", age: "12" },
                { name: "Mary May", age: "1" },
            ];
        },
    },
    tableColumns: {
        type: Array,
        default: function() {
            return [
                { title: "Name", field: "name", sorter: "string", width: 200, editor: true },
                { title: "Age", field: "age", sorter: "number", align: "right", formatter: "progress" },
            ];
        },
    },
    isLoading: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    },
},
mounted() {
    // instantiate Tabulator
    this.tabulator = new Tabulator(this.$refs.table, {
        placeholder: "loading data...",
        //placeholder: "<font-awesome-icon icon='circle-notch' spin size='2x' />",
        data: this.tableData, // link data to table (passed as prop)
        columns: this.tableColumns, // define table columns (passed as prop)
    });
},
```

everything works well besides indicating to the user that data is loading. I first tried using the placeholder option (http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/layout#placeholder) but realized it is not applicable because it is also rendered when no data is displayed.

is there a way to tell Tabulator to preferably render a loading spinner or a text, based on my prop `isLoading`?

Comment: Where is your api call? Is it in the parent component?

Comment: yes. it's in the parent component. I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tabulator has a built in loading overlay when it is loading data via ajax, which can be customised on the ***ajaxLoaderLoading*** option

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
    ajaxLoaderLoading:"<span>Loading Data</span>",
});
```

If you want you want to load your data outside of Tabulator and then load the data in with the ***setData*** command, then this is outside of the scope of tabulator.

The easiest approach to this would be to absolutely position an element over the Tabulator that is shown when you trigger your DB load.

Comment: thanks oli. I now realized I was using Tabulator outside it's intended usage :|

Comment: In tabulator 5.0, I get invalid table constructor option: ajaxLoaderLoading =

Comment: @EdwardGaere in tabulator 5 it is now called: dataLoaderLoading, however I can't get it to work

Answer (score 2):

In tabulator 5, the new option is called `dataLoaderLoading`. According to the [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/options#table) you can pass an 'html'. In the code, this can be a string or an html component. I think there is a bug when you pass a string and the html is not correctly generated (from what I can tell the way the Template element is used). So to get it to work I had to pass the html element, something in the lines of:

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = '<div style="display:inline-block;" class="d-flex flex-row">' +
                    '<div>Loading... </div>' +
                    '<div class="ml-2 activity-sm" data-role="activity" data-type="atom" data-style="dark"></div>' +
                '</div>';
const dataLoaderLoading = template.content.firstChild;
...
new Tabulator("#mytable", {
    dataLoaderLoading: dataLoaderLoading,
    ...
```